# Why would headlights stop working after turning over

Tags: electrical, headlight, pontiac, gm

I have a 2006 Pontiac G6. When I walk up to the vehicle and unlock it, the headlights turn on.

After I get into the vehicle and turn it over, I cannot turn the headlights back on. Fog beams and turn signals work fine, but I can't turn the low beams back on.

What could cause a vehicle's headlights to only be faulty after starting?

Edit: I should mention I can turn my brights on, but regular headlights (low beams) are non-functional.

Comment: Did you actually check the high beams, or are you saying no matter what setting the head lights are on, you see nothing from them?

Comment: After turning over, I can use turn signals, high beams, and foglights. Low beams are completely unresponsive.

Comment: I found this consumer complaint board that seems to map to your issue.  http://www.carcomplaints.com/Pontiac/G6/2008/lights/low_beam_not_working.shtml

Comment: (I am not familiar with the exact wiring of this vehicle)  I am wondering if the headlight before you enter the vehicle are controlled by a BCM, while after the ignition is on, the BCM stops supplying power to the headlights.  The headlight switch would normally turn the headlights on once the ignition is on.  This would mean the headlight switch is bad.  Would need to check the schematics to determine if my theory is correct.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: Oh yeah I did. Turns out I'm an idiot and completely confused my highs for my lows. Lows were always out and my vehicle turns on the highs when I unlock it. My confusion was reinforced when I was pulle over by a police officer, he looked at what I described, and was equally baffled. New low bulbs fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out what went wrong was my car was turning on the brights (highs) when I would go to unlock it, and the regular (lows) headlights were never working. I thought the car was turning on the lows when I went to unlock it. New bulbs fixed the problem.

Little anecdote: I was extra perplexed when I was pulled over at night for driving using my fog lights, showed the cop what I described and he had no clue what was up.